# How to sort VB.net array in ASC

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting, arr

Firstly I have to admit I'am beginner in VB.net. I have this code that have to sort array in ascending order. Firstly it will request how much array size and then insert a data. But I face problem to make it working .Can anyone help me for this? Below is my code :

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()

        Dim A(20) As Integer
        Dim num, i, j, k, arr, temp As Integer

        Console.Write("enter size num:")
        Dim add = Console.ReadLine

        If Integer.TryParse(add, num) Then
            'Console.WriteLine("valid. num = " & num)
            For i = 0 To num - 1
                Console.Write("enter num:")
                A(i) = Console.ReadLine

            Next i

            For i = 0 To num - 1
                For j = i + 1 To num - j
                    If A(i) > A(j) Then
                        temp = A(i)
                        A(i) = A(j)
                        A(j) = temp
                    End If
                Next j
                Console.Write(A(i))
            Next i
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid.Data is not number")
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Thanks and any help will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: _" I face problem to make it working"_ what was the problem? However, it's simple as `Array.Sort(A)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I still can't make it sorting in ascending order . When I run the code ,it will show the list of array but not in ascending order

Comment: Please show the new code containing Array.Sort(A) that still doesn't work.

Comment: When you run the code what result do you actually get?

Answer (score 2):

The immediate cause of your problem is that your

```
Console.Write(A(i))
```

is being invoked before you have completed the sorting operation. A secondary problem is that you are not validating the entered numbers, and you really ought to specify `Option Strict On` at the top of the code and clean up the compilation errors that result.

If you are writing this as an exercise, that's fine but for production purposes you should prefer Tim Schmelter's method.

Comment: Ha! Yes I should have seen that.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned your problem. However, in general sorting an `Int32()` is very easy, you can use [`Array.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Array.Sort(A) ' finished '
```

Comment: Is it possible I can sorting the same like my code given ?Btw thanks

Comment: @art: i have currently not the time to investigate your algorithm further. But in productiuon code use `Array.Sort`, it's much clearer, safer and more efficient.